# Installing Gnome Software center for Ubuntu 18.04 on Chromebook

Tags: 18.04, gnome, xfce, chromebook

So I have a Samsung chromebook. I put Ubuntu on it using the crouton and it installed ubuntu 16.04 with xfce. I was able to update the system to 18.04 and have confirmed that it is actually running this version. It still is running the xfce. I have made sure that everything is up to date.

**So my question:**
I want to be able to install and run the gnome software center.
How do I go about doing this?
Do I need to change from xfce to gnome?
I am brand new to this system, but I am starting to be able to use the basic terminal functions. If you can help me by giving me a link or help, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You can install `gnome-software`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change your desktop environment to do this. Just open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

You will find a launcher named `Software` in your application menu in the `System`-category.